# jQuery plugin 'this.each is not a function'

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create my first jQuery plugin and I am geting the error `this.each is not a function`, which is referencing this line `return this.each(function() {` in the `bindUi` method. I thought that `this` referred to the "jQuery object the plugin was invoked on", which in my case would be the `#location` node I used when creating my plugin with `$('#location').locationSearch()`, right? I get this error on page load.

Here is my plugin code:

```
(function($) {  
  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) {

      return this.each(function() {

        var settings = {
          //none yet
        };

        if ( options ) { 
          $.extend( settings, options );
        }        
        methods.log('init');

        //attach events
        methods.bindUi();        
      });

    },

    destroy : function( ) {
       return this.each(function(){ });
    },

    bindUi : function() {

      return this.each(function() {

        methods.log('bindUi');
        this.click(function() {
          methods.log('clicked');
        });

      });

    },    

    log : function(text) {
      if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        window.console.log(text);
      };
    }
} // end methods

  jQuery.fn.locationSearch = function(method) { 
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    
  };
})( jQuery );
```

I am also a little confused if every one of my methods needs to use `return this.each(function() { ..` or if only the init and destroy methods use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call

```
methods.bundUi.apply(this);
```

in your `init` method.

If you only do `methods.bindUi()`, then `this` inside `bindUi` will refer to the `methods` object.

**Update:**

Oh I just saw it. You are calling `methods.bindUi()` **inside** the `each` loop. Then `this` will refer to the current *DOM element*. So the question is now, what do you want to refer to inside `bindUi`? All the selected elements, or only the current one from the loop?

Here are the two possibilites:

**A: All elements**

```
init : function( options ) {
    this.each(function() {
        var settings = {
            //none yet
        };
        if ( options ) { 
            $.extend( settings, options );
        }        
        methods.log('init');   // <- this might be also better outside the loop
    });
    //attach events
    methods.bindUi.apply(this);    // <- called outside the each loop 

    return this;
}
```

*(no need to change `bindUi`)*

**B: One element**. `this` inside the `each` loop in `init` will refer to the current *DOM element*. We deal with only one element at the time, so we don't need to use `each` in the `bindUi` method. (still use `methods.bindUi.apply(this)` in `init` (but inside the loop, just like you already have it)). But you can't call `bindUi` from the outside anymore (i.e. you can't call `.locationSearch('bindUi')`).

```
bindUi : function() {
    // don't need `each`, as `this` will refer to only one element.
    methods.log('bindUi');
    $(this).click(function() {
          methods.log('clicked');
    });
},
```

A third solution would indeed be to just change `this` to `$(this)` inside the `bindUi` function. This will definitely work, but has two "misconceptions":

- If the function is called via `.locationSearch('bindUi')` then `this` will already be a jQuery object and calling `$(this)` is redundant.
- If you call the function from the `each` loop in `init`, then `this` will refer to ***one*** DOM element. So calling `$(this)` is necessary, but using `each` to loop over *one* element is pointless.

---

> I am also a little confused if every one of my methods needs to use return `this.each(function() { ..` or if only the `init` and `destroy` methods use it?

Every method that should be callable via `.locationSearch(method)` should `return this`.

Comment: I still get the same error when I replace `methods.bindUi();` with `methods.bindUi.apply(this);`.

Comment: That fixed it and now everything is working perfectly ... and I am on my way writing some code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try `$(this).each(`.

jQuery usually lets you use `this` to refer to the pure HTML element (not the jQuery wrapped one).  You have to wrap it again to gain jQuery functionality.

Comment: So, it works now if I use `methods.bindUi.apply(this);` and `$(this)`.

Comment: @Felix, it seems like the docs say not to use `$(this)` inside of a plugin, but I can't get it to work without it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @bababa: I updated my answer. have a look at it. Yes, `$(this)` *seems* to solve the problem, but actually, you have a logic problem here.